# React Jest cannot r-Read properties of undefined Instance

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ts-jest

I have a class that creates a static object named instance

```
export class AppInsightsLogger {
    private readonly _correlationId: string;
    private readonly _appInsights: ApplicationInsights;
    
    private static instance: AppInsightsLogger;
    
    private constructor() {
        const appInsightsSnippet: Snippet = {
        config: {
            connectionString: config.appInsightsConnString,
        },
        };
    
        this._appInsights = new ApplicationInsights(appInsightsSnippet);
        this._appInsights.loadAppInsights();
        this._correlationId = getCorrelationId();
    }
    
    public static get Instance(): AppInsightsLogger {
        return this.instance || (this.instance = new this());
    }
    
    // omitted

}
```

I am trying to Mock this using jest like this

```
// Setup for some mock attempts below
const trackEventMock = jest.fn(() => { Promise.resolve });
const mockLoggerInstance = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
return {
    trackEvent: trackEventMock,
};
```

In my actual test when it gets to line "signInLink.trigger('click');" This is where the test fails and I get the error

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Instance')
> ```

```
  74 |     // underlying library each time and so tests won't fail here if 
  75 |     // an issue exists in the class, which the class tests should detect
> 76 |     AppInsightsLogger.Instance.trackEvent(logProperties);
     |                       ^
  77 | }
  78 |
  79 | function reloadWithoutCustomQueryParams(): void {

  at trackLinkClick (src/pages/register/verifyemail/controllers/signin-link.controller.ts:76:23)
  at HTMLAnchorElement.handleLinkClick (src/pages/register/verifyemail/controllers/signin-link.controller.ts:55:5)
  at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5429:27)
  at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5233:28)
  at Object.trigger (node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:8715:12)
  at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:8793:17)
  at Function.each (node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:381:19)
  at jQuery.fn.init.each (node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:203:17)
  at jQuery.fn.init.trigger (node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:8792:15)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/register/verifyemail/controllers/__tests__/signin-link.controller.spec.ts:126:20)
```

The other attempt is like this

```
// Mock attempt 2: This mock allows me to mock the Instance get method, but when running tests,
// error in the code under test that trackEvent is not a method
 jest.mock('../../../../../common/utils/loggers/app-insights.logger.util', () => {
   class LoggerMock {
     static Instance = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
       return {
         trackEvent: jest.fn().mockImplementation((logProperties: LogProperties) => { }),
       };
     });

     trackEvent = jest.fn().mockImplementation((logProperties: LogProperties) => { });
   }

   return {
     AppInsightsLogger: LoggerMock,
   };
 });
```